# trouble exteding netlogo minesweeper code

Tags: netlogo, minesweeper

I'm new to netlogo and trying to extend the minesweeper code by changing the tiles to hexagons instead of squrares.  I can't seem to get the clear procedure to clear all the appropriate tiles or set the labels for all that should be set. How i'm interpreting it to work is that when called clear will first have the clicked hexagon die and if there is a marker present then that will die too, next it asks each hexagon to count the number of its neighbors that have a bomb on it and set its total variable to that number, if total is greater than 0 it should label itself with that number or else it should be cleared as well.  What am i missing?

```
globals [
  clock             ;; how many seconds the game has lasted so far
  game-started?     ;; initially false, becomes true when player first presses GO
  game-over?        ;; initially false, becomes true if the player loses
  ;;total
]

breed [ hexagons hex ]    ;; these are the green squares the player hasn't tested yet
hexagons-own [hex-neighbors]
breed [ mines mine ]             ;; the mines (initially invisible)
breed [ markers marker ]          ;; show where the player thinks mines are

to setup
  clear-all
  set clock 0
  set game-started? false
  set game-over? false
  set-default-shape hexagons "hex"

  set-default-shape mines "bomb"
  set-default-shape markers "flag"
  ask patches
    [ sprout-hexagons 1
        [ set color magenta + 3 ;; 
        ;; shift even columns down
          if pxcor mod 2 = 0
            [ set ycor ycor - 0.5 ] 
         ]
        set pcolor sky - 3
     ]
  ;; now set up the hex-neighbors agentsets
  ask hexagons
    [ ifelse pxcor mod 2 = 0
        [ set hex-neighbors hexagons-on patches at-points [[0 1] [1 0] [1 -1] [0 -1] [-1 -1] [-1       0]] ]
        [ set hex-neighbors hexagons-on patches at-points [[0 1] [1 1] [1  0] [0 -1] [-1  0] [-1 1]] ] ]


  ;; make the number of mines determined by the mine-count slider
  ask n-of mine-count patches [
    sprout-mines 1 [
      set color black
      if pxcor mod 2 = 0
            [ set ycor ycor - 0.5 ]
      hide-turtle
    ]
  ]

  top-scores
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if game-over? [
    ask markers with [any? mines-here] [ die ]
    ask markers [ set color gray  - 2 ]
    ask mines [ show-turtle ]
    set game-over? true
    ask patches [ set pcolor red ]
    stop
  ]
  if not game-started? [
    ;; this must be the first time through GO, so start the clock
    reset-timer
    set game-started? true
  ]
  set clock timer
  if all? hexagons [any? mines-here] [
    ;; you win!!!
    ask mines [ show-turtle ]
    ask patches [ set pcolor blue ]
    write-to-file
    stop
  ]
  if mouse-down? [
    ask patch (mouse-xcor) (mouse-ycor) [
      ifelse any? mines-here
        [ set game-over? true ]   ;; aiggghhhh!
        [ clear ]                 ;; whew!
    ]
  ]
  tick
end

to clear  ;; patch procedure
  ask hexagons-here [ die ]
  ask markers-here [ die ]
  ask hexagons
    [let total count hex-neighbors with [any? mines-here]
      ifelse total > 0
        [set plabel word total "  "]          
    ;; if none of our neighbors have mines on them, then they can
    ;; be cleared too, to save the user from extra clicking
        [ ask hex-neighbors with [any? hexagons-here]
          [ clear ] ]]

end

to mark/unmark
  if not mouse-inside? [ stop ]
  ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [
      if any? hexagons-here [
      ifelse any? markers-here
        [ ask markers-here [ die ] ]
        [ sprout-markers 1 [ set color yellow ]] ] ]
end


to write-to-file
  file-open "highScores.txt"
  file-print (word "Bomb count: " mine-count "     Time: " clock)
  file-print("")
  file-close
end


to top-scores
  file-open "highScores.txt"
  while [not file-at-end?]
  [output-print file-read-line]
  file-close
end
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what, and where, the coding problem is that you're facing?

Comment: i believe that the issue is with in the Clear procedure. specifically relating to the hex-neighbors.  it's supposed to have the hexagons check if there are any bombs in the neighboring areas and if there are label itself with how many if there aren't any then is should be clearing those hexagons.  the issue that i'm running into is that not all hexagons that should be cleared are being cleared and not all turtles adjacent to bombs are being labeled.